# Laravel Search not working with error massage

Tags: php, laravel, search, laravel-5

What i need is use this search which has a selectable dropdown.see the following screenshot.

[image]
These selected data are comes under trainee_division which is in **registerdetails** data table.here is the controller function i`m developing.

```
$query = $request->search;
        $queryType = $request->institute;
        $items = DB::table('registerdetails');


         if($queryType == 'Operation' || $queryType == 'operation' ){
                $items = $items->where('Operation', '=',"%$queryType%");
         }

        $items = $items->get();
        return view('registeredusers.admindivisiondetails')->with('items',$items);
```

Relevant view is like this

```
<form action="divisiondetailsSearch" method="post" class="form-inline">  
                <select name="institute" id="institute">
                  <option selected="selected" value="Operation">Operation</option>
                  <option value="NPA">NPA</option>
                  <option value="BTS-Kurunegala">BTS-Kurunegala</option>
                  <option value="INOC">INOC</option>
                  <option value="RNO">RNO</option>
                  <option value="Implementation">Implementation</option>
                  <option value="RAN">RAN</option>
                  <option value="CEE">CEE</option>
                  <option value="BTS-Jaffna">BTS-Jaffna</option>
                  <option value="BTS-Colombo">BTS-Colombo</option>
                  <option value="Transmission">Transmission</option>
                  <option value="BTS-Rathnapura">BTS-Rathnapura</option>
                  <option value="IBS">IBS</option>
                  <option value="NS">NS</option>
                  <option value="PCN">PCN</option>
                  <option value="SQ">SQ</option>
                  <option value="Pro-Transmission">Pro-Transmission</option>
                  <option value="BTS-Kandy">BTS-Kandy</option>
                </select>

                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" name="_token" />
                       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
                       </form>
```

i`m getting this error.

[image]

can anyone help me to get solved this one please.

Comment: column name are case sensitive *Operation*  .i guess in your table *Operation* column  all character in  lower case

Comment: Operation and other atas  not a data column those are data which is in a traainee_division data column

Comment: it seems you need like query like this $items = $items->where('Operation','like',"%$queryType%");

Comment: change the column name $items = $items->where('traainee_division','like',"%$queryType%"); @Dasun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the query to

```
if($queryType == 'Operation' || $queryType == 'operation' ){
                $items = $items->where('traainee_division', 'like',"%$queryType%");
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment you need `like` query to `traainee_division` column

```
$items = $items->where('traainee_division','like',"%$queryType%");
```

**note :**
      your matching `value` with `value` . you need to match `value` with table `column value` using `like` query above .

Answer (score 0):

Please check you table first it seems like there is no **Operation** Column in table..

it might be help you.